# Current date with the selected date to be passed

Tags: iphone

I want to pass two dates 1st which i will select from the datetime picker & 2nd the current date of the iPhone then what is the process for the current date to pass to the webservice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass current date as a string through url.

```
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yy-MM-dd"];
NSString *dateString=[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"Today is %@",dateString);
```

Comment: If i want to take current time also than what should I do?